# How to lock certain feature of my android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I was doing an android app and I want to lock some feature temporally for each user.

What I want is to lock say 1 activity to be used before someone performs a predefined task say share on facebook, only then I want them to view the activity.

How can I achieve this? It is for application, just like games lock the level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make an application/user profile and save it in a [database or in the shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Yes, it's the standard way to hold settings.

Comment: For more complex settings you could use the PreferenceActivity, which is automatically saved to the SharedPreferences:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

you could simply check if a certain task has been performed prior to opening the activity you want locked.